# Different constructors with default vaules Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Is it possible to get equivalent of this code with Lombok's annotations? I tried many different configurations with @AllArgsArgument, @RequiredArg, @NoArgs. Would be great to make them final with default null / 0 values if not provided in construcor.

```
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
public class ProductBasicDto implements Serializable {

@Builder.Default
private Long id = null;
private String name;
private String category;
private BigDecimal price;
private int stock;
private String shortDescription;

public ProductBasicDto(){

}

public ProductBasicDto(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ProductBasicDto(String name, String category) {
    this(name);
    this.category = category;
}

public ProductBasicDto(String name, String category, BigDecimal price) {
    this(name, category);
    this.price = price;
}

public ProductBasicDto(String name, String category, BigDecimal price, int stock) {
    this(name, category, price);
    this.stock = stock;
}

public ProductBasicDto(String name, String category, BigDecimal price, int stock, String shortDescription) {
    this(name, category, price, stock);
    this.shortDescription = shortDescription;

}

public ProductBasicDto(Long id, String name, String category, BigDecimal price, int stock, String shortDescription) {
    this(name, category, price, stock, shortDescription);
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Comment: Aside: can I suggest you reverse the order of the constructor chaining? the no-arg constructor should call `this(null)`; the 1-arg constructor should call `this(name, null);` etc. This way, all of the fields are always assigned, so you can make them `final`. Or, use the builder pattern.

Comment: Yeah right. But I still need to call constructors in my code? Cannot lombok do that?

Comment: Is it not that `@Builder` pattern is exactly for this kind of stuff?

Comment: Yeah but I need these constructors in persistence context.

Comment: On a side note the @Builder.default and the default null value for the field « id » are not necessary

Comment: yea i know, thanks anyway :)